# AWS Cognito Temporary Credentials in Cookie

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, ember.js, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am writing an Ember app where I want to allow users to upload pdf files, and I am using AWS S3 for file storage.  Because I don't want to hard code my AWS creds, I am using AWS Cognito to create temporary credentials to authenticate users to S3 when they want to upload/download files.  I created an Identity Pool on AWS for the users, and have configured the associated IAM roles for authenticated and unauthenticated users (authenticated users get read only access to one of my S3 buckets).  I am using my Rails backend (which uses Devise) as the authentication provider for my identity pool.  For my frontend authentication I am using Ember Simple Auth with the provided Devise authenticator, so the user must be logged in in order to request a token.  Here are the steps I take to obtain the temporary credentials:

1)  Get an AWS Cognito Identity Id and Token from my backend (using get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity method from Ruby AWS SDK on my backend)

2)  Create a new CognitoIdentityCredentials object using the Identity Id and Token to obtain temporary credentials, and store the creds in a cookie (using js-cookie).

Code:

```
        var AWS = window.AWS;
        AWS.config.region = "us-west-2";
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'us-west-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
            IdentityId: response.identity_id,
            Logins: {
                'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': response.token
            }
        });
        AWS.config.credentials.get(function() {
            var date = new Date(AWS.config.credentials.expireTime);
            Cookies.set("cognito_creds", { accessKeyId: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey, sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken }, { expires: date } );
        });
```

I understand that storing important information such as AWS credentials in a cookie is a big no-no, and is definitely not secure.  But keep in mind, I am using HTTPS, the credentials expire after an hour, and the IAM role associated with the credentials only gives read-only access to one of my S3 buckets.

My question is: Is it worth the security risk to store these creds as cookies so that I don't have to get a token from my backend every page refresh, or does this approach leave me too vulnerable?

EDIT:  To clarify, the alternate solution that I am thinking of would be to store the credentials as properties on an Ember service on the frontend, and get a token from my backend every time the page reloads, but this doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612530/how-to-persist-cognito-identity-across-pages-in-browser) has some similar aspects, it might be worth a read. The short version is, either should be alright. It sounds like you've scoped down the credentials perfectly, so you've limited the blast radius if you opt to save them.

If you want to keep the latency down, it isn't a bad way to go. If you're willing to sacrifice that latency or are concerned with the privacy of what could be read from S3, you could go for getting them remotely.