# AWS cognito for javascript webapp. How to check if cognito token has expired or not

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So I have a basic webapp, and Im trying to create user access control using AWS cognito. I have a custom authorisation provider and upon entering correct username password. I do the following in my login page:

```html
//Successful Login
  var creds = AWS.config.credentials;
  creds.params.IdentityId = output.identityId;
  creds.params.Logins = {'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': output.token}; 
       
//Store token in browser cache
  localStorage.setItem('token', output.token);
  localStorage.setItem('id', output.identityId);
       
//Launch dashboard 
  window.location = "./index.html";
```

Once I redirect the user to the dashboard, I trigger a onLoad function to check whether the user has correct login credentials and not expired ones. Using this:

```html
//read browser cache
  var id = localStorage.getItem('id');
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
   
//validate session
   
  AWS.config.region = 'ap-northeast-1';
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: id,
 Logins: {'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': token}
  });
   
//check if session is still active
  if(AWS.config.credentials.expired) window.location = "./session-expire.html";
```

Problem is the expired property is always true. no matter what I do.  How do you guys check if the credentials are valid?.

Thanks in advance,
Rajan

Comment: Refer this this might clear some issues https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/CognitoSyncDemo/src/com/amazonaws/cognito/sync/demo/DeveloperAuthenticationProvider.java#L97

Answer (score 1):

In the code samples you provided, you never acquire credentials. You set up the credentials provider, but do not call any services with it, or explicitly try to get the credentials.

Secondly, the credentials are not persisted across page loads.

This will lead to the credentials being expired in your code samples.

This question may help you, just replace facebook with your own developer auth flow. [AWS.config.credentials are null between page requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025339/aws-config-credentials-are-null-between-page-requests)